# Javascript multidimensional array format

Tags: javascript

I need to construct a multidimensional array looks like below in a for loop

```
var  dataSet = [
                 {color: '#ff00aa', data: [[0,3533]]},
                 {color: 'red', data: [[1,3325]]},
                 {color: 'yellow', data: [[2,3003]]},

             ];
```

Dynamically I need to push the values to dataSet array. I have tried with the below code

```
 for(var j=0;j<chartDataArray.length;j++){
        dataSet.push({
            "color" : 'red',
            "data" : [[0,3533]]
        });
 }
```

Its working fine but If I make the add some dynamic value to the data variable then it gives an error. Please find the below code

```
for(var j=0;j<chartDataArray.length;j++){
        dataSet.push({
            "color" : 'red',
            "data" : [[chartDataArray[j]]]
        });
        }
```

Comment: It's a quiz and we need to guess _what_ error he's getting ...

Comment: @somethinghere Nope.

Comment: No if I add `"data" : [[0,3533]]` its working fine. Iam not able to push to it dynamically.

Comment: Why are you wrapping it in a double array afterwards, though? Thats just curiosity. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say

```
chartDataArray = [
                     [0, 533]
                 ];
```

if you push it the way you do, you'll end up with

```
[{
    "color" : 'red',
    "data" : [[[0, 533]]]
}]
```

with an extra nested array which isn't what you want.

In this case, try:

```
for(var j=0;j<chartDataArray.length;j++){
        dataSet.push({
            "color" : 'red',
            "data" : [chartDataArray[j]]
        });
}
```

If it contains numbers, let's say:

```
chartDataArray = [0, 533];
```

you would end up with

```
[{
    "color" : 'red',
    "data" : [[0]]
},
{
    "color" : 'red',
    "data" : [[533]]
}]
```

Which also isn't what you want. You'll have to push the numbers by pairs. Try:

```
for(var j=0;j<chartDataArray.length;j+=2){
        dataSet.push({
            "color" : 'red',
            "data" : [[chartDataArray[j], chartDataArray[j+1]]]
        });
}
```

Comment: thank you, chartDataArray  is an array so the first one is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

It is too much square brackets
Try `[chartDataArray[j]]`. `chartDataArray` should contain items like

```
{
[[0,3533]],
[[1,3533]]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use :

```
var data = [[chartDataArray[j]]];
dataset[dataset.length]={
    "color" : 'red',
    "data" : data
}
```

Let me know...